# HKCR File association doesn't work

Tags: windows, registry, nsis, file-association

I have been facing an issue that a particular file association behaviour doesn't work when I double click.
I am using .dms extension which will use on my desktop application.

Firstly I removed all keys with .dms under the

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.dms
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\dms_auto_file
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.dms
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\dms_auto_file

Then I setup registry key under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dms 
REG_SZ : (Default) dms_auto_file

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dms_auto_file\shell\open\command
REG_SZ : (Default) "C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp\test.exe"  "dms" "%1"
```

However when I double click on the .dms file. It always says
[image]

Could you please help me ?
Thank you for any helps.

Comment: I tried below but still do not work!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956122/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-a-program-without-making-it-the-default-pro

Comment: Total guess, but are you running on Windows x64? Try `SetRegView 64`.